# Good IMAP Email Client to Handle 1000+ Emails

Tags: email, client, imap

We use Thunderbird as our email client in the office and use IMAP (through Google Apps). But it takes some time to sync folders and emails because we have created more than 300 folders according to shipments and customer names. Further we need to keep increase folders in the future as well.

So can you please tell me a good way or an email client to handle these emails ?. We have configured this email account in to about 8 PCs. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

300 folders and "1000+" e-mails is nothing. I'm behind [Trojitá](http://trojita.flaska.net/), a fast Qt IMAP e-mail client, so this is what I recommend, but any decent software shall work just fine for you anyway.

That said, this is probably OT for stackoverflow.